# What's a good i18n plugin for Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, internationalization, bower

I'm looking to set up internationalization for an app I'm developing. I've found a good number of bower packages that seem to do what I'm looking for, but only partially.

All of them seem to either be able to set a text programatically in the HTML to an appropriately translated string OR handle certain tags in the HTML and automatically set the value to the translated version of the string.

Unfortunately, I can't find something that does both. There is text in my UI that just never changes and I basically feel like it's wrong to have to write code to set those strings that I never touch otherwise. There is also text that appears dynamically so being able to set it whenever I need to is absolutely necessary.

Don't get me wrong, I don't have a problem with setting text myself but I feel like that would result in some pretty ugly and difficult to maintain code...

If I somehow missed a plugin or a package, or if you have a different solution that can do what I need, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Although opinion-based questions are not generally accepted here, a cordova plugin I used recently for one of my own application is this: [jquery i18n properties](https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties)

Comment: @anima_incognita I don't particularly see how this is an opinion question... I am looking for a plugin that can auto-handle some translations and still let me set strings whenever I need to. Your suggestion satisfies only one of these criteria.

Comment: Personally I agree with you that asking for tools or programs to help people out should be generally accepted. Regarding your question, the plugin I suggested lets you have the fixed text in your ui, while allowing you to handle both the HTML tags in your code and the text of the dynamic content. In my application, which was small-scale (3 fixed pages and a lot of dynamic content) it took me 2 hours to set it up for 5 languages which I consider an acceptable time. Best of luck with your search.